# Subscript out of range when opening XLSX file that was downloaded from SAP

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a macro wherein I would download data from SAP and then the rest of the macro would be editing the data. I'm encountering a problem wherein after downloading from SAP, "subscript out of range" error would occur whenever I would switch to the newly downloaded data (when it is already open). The file names that I use for each data set that I download already has a specific name that is stored in specific cells in the file. I've noticed that once I close the newly downloaded file and open it again, the VBA code to switch to the new file would then work seamlessly.

Here is a part of the code where I am going to switch to the file where the name it's using is stored in the MPV2_Name cell:

```
Sub MPV9480_Edit()
'
' MPV9480Edit Macro

Dim application
Dim Filename As String
Dim Filepath As String

Windows("1205 Raw Data File.xlsm").Activate
Filename = Worksheets("Inputs").Range("MPV2_Name").Value

Windows(Filename).Activate
'Here is where the subscript out of range error occurs

End sub
```

Comment: Give us a proof that such window exist. If windows("blabla").activate fails, it means there is no such window "blabla", Check what windows are. Your error should be this: "Run time error 9, subscription out of range"

Comment: @bankeris I was unable to get a screenshot, but yes that is the error that I was getting. The code works after closing the file and opening it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check what windows are visible code below. There is few scenarios I think.

1. Your window is not visible
2. Your window belongs to other workbook.
3. Maybe you should activate workbook ? :)

   Sub check_windows()
   For Each w In Windows
   MsgBox w.Caption
   Next
   End Sub

Comment: I checked it now and it didn't read the other files that I just downloaded... It seems like the newly downloaded files are being opened under a a different Excel session. What should I do?

Comment: EDIT: I got a workaround by using Workbooks.Open but it would open up the files again, which would eat up memory. It works but please teach me if you know a better way